# How can I specify NotificationHub as output Trigger for Azure Functions in Visual Studio

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-notificationhub

How can I specify an output parameter for azure function develop in Visual studio for NotificationHub: 
My function looks like this:

```
        [FunctionName("DoSomething")]
        public static void Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = _Connection)]string queueItem, 
            TraceWriter log,
            [????] IAsyncCollector<Notification> notification)
        {
         //.....   
        }
```

Azure function in the azure.portal has json with output configuration but in the code in visual studio It does not have a decorator like NotificationHub similar to specifying Queue output :  `[Queue("myQueueName", Connection = "myconnection")] IAsyncCollector<Notification> notification`. How can I define an output parameter that has the information that appears in the portal?

```
   {
      "type": "notificationHub",
      "name": "notification",
      "hubName": "mynotification-hub",
      "connection": "CONNECTION",
      "direction": "out",
      "tagExpression": "{Tag}"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.NotificationHubs` NuGet package.

Then use the trigger like

```cs
[NotificationHub] out Notification notification
```

or

```cs
[NotificationHub(HubName = "mynotification-hub", ConnectionStringSetting = "CONNECTION", 
                 TagExpression = "{Tag}")] IAsyncCollector<Notification> notification
```

See more in [docs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions#azure-notification-hubs).

Comment: Hi I am getting a strange error where the process or function cli is adding AzureWebJobs as prefix of my connections strings and then how that connection does not exist I get and error:  Run: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'NotifyMobiles.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string 'AzureWebJobsSERVICEBUS' is missing or empty.

Comment: Normally works for other bindings, but I don't have Notification binding with me now. Try adding this long named connection string to config?